# How to call node module in express rendered view?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, handlebars.js

I'm having a really difficult time trying to understand how to pass called data to my view. I'm requiring the Mozscape node module in a little application i'm trying to develop but I don't quite understand how I'm to pass the information into my view. I would imagine that I need to create the object in my router and call the function in my view. Mozscapes returns an object which I would pass into my view and then use **Handlebars** to iterate through the data?

Here's the code from my router below

```
//pull in express
const express = require('express');
//declare router as variable for index view
const index   = express.Router();

//mozscape for seo data
var Mozscape = require('mozscape').Mozscape;

//mozscape expects accessid and secretid
//only allows for 1 call per 10 seconds with free plan
//need to add to env file later
var moz = new Mozscape('mozscape-6d6ab44235', '846aca62a6db69661c81b784115e8a9');


//dummy data
var business =
    {
        name:       'Party Corner',
        address:    '123 Main Street, Red Bank, NJ',
        hours:      'Monday through Friday 9 - 5',
        website:    'http://www.partycorner.com/',
        category:   'Party Supplies',
        imgUrl:     'https://scontent.fewr1-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/14361226_10154547117788288_58127422291546970_o.jpg?oh=126b8240a8ac27dfb06b57ed51f4320e&oe=5A5A8FCC'
    };


//middleware to process data for view
var businessSeo;
businessSeo = function (req, res, next) {
    req.businessSeo = moz.urlMetrics(business.website, ['page_authority', 'links', 'domain_authority'], function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('requesting data from moz');

        console.log(res);
        return res;
    });
};
index.use(businessSeo);
//logging the data
console.log(businessSeo);





//use declare router for http methods
//get request for index with request, response, next params
index.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    //render response  from server using index view from declared path in app.js
    res.render('index', {
        //declare {{ title }} used in main template extended as default template
        title: "Business Directory",
        //use business as object keys and values.. |key val|
        business: business,
        body:
            {
                description: 'This is a business for the business directory, how neat is that?'
            },
        mozData: businessSeo
    })
});


module.exports = index;
```

I'm just trying to log the object in the front end right now and it returns that moz is not defined. I imagine I would need to move my business object into it's own variable (later quired response) and then put the function right into my router and access the business website from there?

Expected output:

```
Object {pda: 24.123844872381643, uid: 187, upa: 33.43142060578742}
```

Comment: Almost positive you need to call `next()` instead of `return res` because this will stop the middleware at this function and return that before even hitting your main response function for the **/** path. Change it next() and you might be good.

Comment: Hey Andrei that's what I was thinking too, but it turns out that it doesn't need to be middleware at all. I answered my own question, posting here in a minute. Need to find a way to make it more elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function storeData(param) {
    businessSeo = param;
}

//middleware not needed to process data for view

businessSeo = moz.urlMetrics(business.website, ['page_authority', 'links', 'domain_authority'], function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('requesting data from moz');

        //console.log(res); sent data to the variable
        storeData(res);
    });






//use declare router for http methods
//get request for index with request, response, next params
index.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    //data has arrived!
    console.log(businessSeo);
```